# how to run build using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have the following folder layout (built using maven deploy plugin):

```
projectrelease
    ├── README.md
    └── com
        └── example
            └── demo
                ├── 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar.md5
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar.sha1
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.pom
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.pom.md5
                │   ├── demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.pom.sha1
                │   ├── maven-metadata.xml
                │   ├── maven-metadata.xml.md5
                │   └── maven-metadata.xml.sha1
                ├── maven-metadata.xml
                ├── maven-metadata.xml.md5
                └── maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

how can I run it using maven cmd?

the project was built using maven executable jar plugin and it can be run by:

```
./projectrelease/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar
```

or

```
java -jar projectrelease/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar
```

I'm looking to run a mvn cmd from the root folder so it will run the entire project

Comment: First if this has been created by maven deploy plugin the project itself is wrongly configured. If you like to use this in another project you have to define it as a dependency (by using coordinates groupId, artifactId, version)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: question was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking to run a mvn cmd from the root folder so it will run the entire project

I don't think these files are runnable "per se" as they are, without some extra tool or Maven plugin. Also, I'm not actually sure what you mean by "run the project". Do you mean compile it? Or run it in some way similar to a normal java execution?

What you have there is the layout of complied Artifacts which belong in a Maven Repository.

Both **Artifact** and **Repository** are specific Maven concepts.

The `.pom` and `.xml` files, the `.sha1` and `.md5` files, are all metadata used by Maven itself to control downloads of the Artifact from a Repository. The `.jar` file is the actual Artifact of interest.

These files are intended to be installed into a repo, and then used by other Maven projects by being referenced as a dependency in the `pom.xml`.

For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The files can be installed in the "local repository" which is filesystem based, and is normally found at `${user.home}/.m2/`

Or you can run a Repository server. Common Repository servers include [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype), [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/Artifactory/) or [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

---

<strike>The other possibility is that the main `.jar` file is executable. In which case, you would run not with Maven, but as a normal Java file:</strike>

```
java -jar demo-0.0.1-20171220.161043-1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may to include manuelly dependency jar, or you can compile your project with dependencies, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).